# nil can't be coerced into Fixnum geting error while update my table through Model after_create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying update my DB after doing some create

I have a two models

one is ratings model and another is names model what I am doing is

in ratings model

```
after_create :update_post_update_attribscore

def update_post_update_attribscore
  self.names.update_attribscore
end
```

And In my companies model

```
def update_attribscore
  rating_size1 = ratings.collect(&:r1).count
  update_attributes(:attrib1 => company_ratings.collect(&:r1).sum.to_f/rating_size1)  
  rating_size2 = ratings.collect(&:r2).count
  update_attributes(:attrib2 => company_ratings.collect(&:r2).sum.to_f/rating_size2)  
  review = rating_size1 + rating_size2
  update_attributes(:reviews => review)
end 

after_update :update_satisfaction

def update_satisfaction
  update_attributes(:satisfaction => (attrib1 + attrib2) / self.reviews
end
```

But now I am getting the following error: `nil can't be coerced into Fixnum`
So here what I wanted to do is after the update of `update_attribscore` and I would like to update the `update_satisfaction` for this where I get data from the above update.

So what is my problem and how can I do it. Can any tell me how to do it.

Comment: You're dividing by `rating_size` which is not defined anywhere?

Comment: sorry that is rating_size1 and rating_size2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are updating the companies model (in update_attribscore) in three steps. update_satisfaction is triggered in every step. You don't say where exactly you're getting the error, but I am guessing that is after the first update (for attrb1), when attrib2 is stil nil.

Do you have any reason for not updating all attributes at once? That way the after_update will only be triggered after all fields are populated. It will be more efficient as well because you'll only hit the database once. That is:

```
 rating_size1 = ratings.collect(&:r1).count
 rating_size2 = ratings.collect(&:r2).count
 review = rating_size1 + rating_size2
 attrb1 = ..../rating_size1
 attrb2 = ..../rating_size1
 update_attributes :attrb1 => attrb1, :attrb2 => attrb2, :review => review
```